# Multiple autocomplete in ace.js

Tags: ace-editor

I am trying to add two different autocomplete list in ace-editor by using two different short cut keys. Ctrl-T should list only the tables and Ctrl-Space should list specific keywords as well as the tables. Please any one could help me with this as I am new to ace-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the **wordList** upon different Shortcut keys and update the 
autocomplete.
Ctrl-Space is used by the ace to trigger the basic auto-completer to come up. I would suggest you use any other shortcut for making a new autocompletion.

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
       name: "myCommand2",
       bindKey: { win: "Ctrl-T", mac: "Cmd-T" },
       exec: function () {
           //Update the Worldlist with tables here and make a call for the autocomplete
           wordList=['table1','table2']; //set of table names
       }
});
```

Similarly, you can bind the other short cut and update the wordList for the autocomplete

```
var staticWordCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {

        callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                caption: word,
                value: word,
                meta: "static"
            };
        }));

    }
}
```